# Set a random class depending on position on page

Tags: javascript, css, random, scroll

JavaScript:

```
var classes = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 20) {
        var cls = classes[Math.floor( Math.random() * classes.length )];
        $('#box').toggleClass(cls);
    }
});
```

CSS:

```css
.a {
    background: red;
    height: 100px;
}
.b {
    background: green;
    height: 200px;
}
.c {
    background: blue;
    height: 300px;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7kbDm/)

What I am trying to do here is modifying the style of a div depending on the scroll position you are on. In this case, when you scroll pass 20 it would change to EITHER one of these 3 conditions (100px in green background / 200px in yellow background / 300px in red background). It's doing the random style change in the demo, however it's constantly changing the style as you scroll. Is there a way to make it stay in the randomly selected  style after you scroll pass that point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a named event using `on` and disable it using `off` after you've changed your class.

```
var classes = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

$(window).on('scroll.changeClass', function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 20) {
        var cls = classes[Math.floor( Math.random() * classes.length )];
        $('#box').toggleClass(cls);
        $(this).off('.changeClass'); // remove the event as we are done here
    }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ck5fa/2/

Comment: Seems to be working! Give me some time to test it out. Thank you so much!

Comment: This could be a dumb question... but when I directly apply the same code doesn't seem to be working. Couldn't figure out what I am missing here.
http://dustintong.com/Untitled-1.html

Comment: Check for errors in your console. You didn't include jQuery in your page (http://d.pr/i/ZsZx+).

Comment: I believe I have jquery included now, but there is another error in the console

Comment: The `on` method was introduced in jQuery 1.7, and you are using `1.3.2`. Upgrade it to the most recent version and it should work fine.

Comment: I just upgrade it to the newest one, there is no error now, nut it's still not doing what's it's doing in the jsfiddle?

Comment: Actually the JavaScript code is working, the class is appended to your element on the window scroll, but you are not noticing the difference because your `#box` CSS definition is after the `a`, `b` and `c` classes, which makes it overwrite your classes background value. Move the `#box` definition to the top of your CSS and it finally should look as expected. =)

Comment: Hmm I see. When I removed the background style on the `#box`, it's actually working. however if I keep the background style and move it before the a,b,c classes, it still overwriting them. Anyway I think this should do it. Thanks!!